# Bootstrap | Placing Images/Spans on top of images, and still be responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to add a Notification and Message button on top of a "profile picture" on my website, that i am having a little fun styling. Now i don't seem to be able to figure out how to place this span with a glyphicon near it, and still have it be responsive.

Here is a picture of what im kinda going for: [PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aJUh.png)

Here is a picture of what i have at the moment: [PICTURE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn6lG.png)

This is the current setup:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 profile-preview">
                <img id="profile-picture" src="assets/person.png">
                <span id="message-button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#message-button{
position: relative;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 5px solid green;
background-color: green;
```

}

I simply have no clue how i would go about moving the glyphicon-comment span up to the image, and still make it responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier for me build it in one file then typing dozens of lines of explaination. The point is to let bootstrap do all the work for you in terms of aligning and centering.

I simply used one css class `col-xs-12` for the profile image, then you simply start a new bootstrap `row` with 2 `div`containers with the class `col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6`. That gives you 2 equal boxes at all times. The rest, styling the buttons and the icons is an easy job.

I hope this helps you to understand the concept, you can copy/paste this code into one HTML file and see the result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Responsive Profile Image with Button</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            background: #3D3A3A;
        }
        .profile-preview {
            /* this centers all child elements */
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 100px;
            background: none;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .profile-picture {
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
        }
        .profile-buttons {
            background: #272424;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            font-size: 3em;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .glyphicon {
            position: relative;
            top: 5px;
            color: #D9D9D9;
        }
        /* Correction of the icon */
        .glyphicon-option-vertical {
            margin-left: 6px;
        }
        /* the green message dots */
        .number-of-messages {
            position: absolute;
            top: -5px;
            background: #8DAE00;
            color: #D9D9D9;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 14px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 profile-preview">
        <img class="profile-picture img-circle" src="http://placekitten.com/262/262/">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <button class="profile-buttons" id="message-button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
                    <span class="number-of-messages">3</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <button class="profile-buttons" id="comment-button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></span>
                    <span class="number-of-messages">2</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In order to change the distance / width of the buttons on different devices, just change the width class of the single groups to get them closer or wider. `*-offset-*` is also very helpful.

You can also use the class `img-responsive` to give your images the `width:100%;height:auto` properties for responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks this worked with a little of tweaking! :) Nice of you to even add in the "number-of-messages" hehe :)